# PLSQL Decode in Where Clause

Tags: sql, plsql, where-clause, decode

would appreciate any help with this, I'm trying to use a `DECODE` statement to produce `IF STATUS = 7 THEN Start Date must be Null`, is this possible in a `WHER`E ?

```
 AND DECODE ( STATUS, 7, NVL ( GMM.START_DATE,1 ) = 1  )
```

Thanks
Gav

Comment: WHERE clause is the section where you write your conditions to get your specific records from the table/s. are your trying to get records WHERE status is 7 and start date is null? you can use decode but if used in WHERE clause, the result should be compared to another value or column.

Answer (score 0):

Yes but you have to use a replacement value for NULL values. Make sure to use a value that is unlikely in the database.
for example :

```
DECODE(status,7,TO_DATE('01-01-1800','MM-DD-RRRR'),start_date) = NVL(start_date,TO_DATE('01-01-1800','MM-DD-RRRR'))
```